# validate that Date of Birth should not be greater than the current date

Tags: asp.net

validate that Date of Birth should not be greater than the current date.
using datetimepicker in asp.net 2.0 and c#..

Comment: Are you asking a question or making a demand?

Comment: i think its demand...........

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing you're lost and are asking a question.

Use CompareValidator and set the type to date, create a hidden field with the current date to compare. Just an idea.

Comment: hey dude iam working on window form application,asp.net 2.0 framework.. and c#.
there i have to use datetimepicker to see customer date of birth..but it should not be greator than current date...so cud u help me..

Comment: Question was tagged with asp.net, next time tag it with the appropriate tag

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the value chosen on the datepicker is less than now. I don't know anything about your datepicker's implementation but in general you're looking to code something like...

```
if (YourDatePicker.SelectedDate > DateTime.Now)
     throw new Exception("Dude, you haven't been born yet!");
```

Comment: cud anyone explain it by giving an example how to validate that Date of Birth should not be greater than the current date. using datetimepicker in asp.net 2.0 and c#..